# How can I set cookie in node js using express framework for an https localhost request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, https

It was working when my client side used HTTP, but now that I've created a self-signed certificate and now my client side is running on HTTPS, the cookie I set in the backend isn't appearing in the browser. My express server is currently running on port 5000 HTTP and my client side is currently running on port 3000 with HTTPS.

backend

```
    const app = express();
    app.use(
      cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: "https://localhost:3000",
      })
    );
    app.use(cookieParser({}));
    app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log("Server is Running on Port " + PORT);
    });
    //from api/auth
const login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
      if (!user)
        return res
          .status(404)
          .json({ success: false, message: "Email or Password Incorrect" });
      const validatePassword = await bcrypt.compare(
        req.body.password,
        user.password
      );
      if (!validatePassword)
        return res
          .status(404)
          .json({ success: false, message: "Email or Password Incorrect" });
  
      const { password, ...others } = user._doc;
      const token = generateJwt(user._id);
        res.cookie("isLogged", true, {
          sameSite: "lax",
          
        });
  
        res.cookie("authToken", token, {
          httpOnly: true,
          sameSite: "lax",
        });
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, user: others });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: err });
    }
  };
```

onClient side

```
   import axios from "axios";
    
    const axiosInstance = axios.create({
      withCredentials: true,
      baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api/",
    });
    
    export default axiosInstance;

  const login = async () => {
    try {
      const data = {
        email: email.current.value,
        password: password.current.value,
        rememberMe: rememberMe.current.checked,
      };
      const res = await axios.post("auth/login", data);
      console.log(res);
    } catch (err) {
     console.error(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: SSL is server-side, not client side. Client does not listen to any port, this: "my client side is currently running on port 3000 with HTTPS" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: if your page (html, js, css) is served using https, then no modern browser lets you access an API over http - I could be wrong, but I don't think so - also, the server at `http://localhost:5000` could only set a cookie for `http://localhost:5000` - so you can't access it in browser code served from `https://localhost:3000`

Comment: based on your code, it seems your server is listening on port 5000 without SSL (`http://localhost:5000`), but it's using CORS for origin: `https://localhost:3000`.

Comment: I mean my  react local dev server is running  on localhost:3000  @Gra